# Spring for client side angularJS single page application architecture

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, spring-boot, angular

After some investigations, I'm wondering about the benefits to use Spring Boot for client side web single page web applications foreseen with angularJS2 and Bootstrap4 ?
We will have to manage the navigation from 3 to 6 SPA and the security (openAM).
The use of Spring Boot for the backend that will embbed REST, activiti, JPA and our business logic seem very valuable.
Any recommandations about such achitecture ?